# What are the differences between the various platform-specific implementations of Function.toString() in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, reflection, cross-platform

I came across this really interesting package on pub.dev recently: [fake_reflection](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_reflection), but the idea of using this in production scares me. My understanding is that the package parses the output of Function.toString() and allows access to function parameter types/names at runtime.

I can imagine using this strategy to build a JSON parsing API that is more developer-friendly than the one in `dart:convert` such as:

`T jsonDecode<T>(String json)`

Someone in the Flutter dev discord told me that Function.toString() has different implementations for different platforms. If that is true, can someone explain the differences or point me in the direction of implementation-specific documentation? If there are other concerns aside from platform differences, what are they? Lastly, has anyone tried using `fake_reflection` or a similar strategy in prod?

Comment: The point is probably that the output of `Function.toString()` isn’t well enough specified that you can rely on it.